# Is there a way to use CarrierWave with Azure these days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, carrierwave, azure-sdk-ruby

I was using CarrierWave gem + google cloud to upload and store files from my project. Unfortunately I need to switch to Azure cloud so I'm trying to implement the same mechanism as previous (basically replace `config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb` with proper values). My current `carrier_wave.rb`:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.application.config.ci
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  else
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: 'Google',
      google_project: Rails.application.config.google_cloud_storage_project,
      google_json_key_string: Rails.application.config.google_cloud_storage_json_key_string
    }
    config.fog_directory = Rails.application.config.google_cloud_storage_bucket_name
  end
end
```

Surprisingly, I don't see anywhere to do it the easy way. I was trying to use https://github.com/unosk/carrierwave-azure but it's 10y old gem which doesn't seem to be maintained.

Is no one using CarrierWave + Azure these days or is there a modern way to do it?

**[EDIT]**

I tried to use [fog-azure-rm](https://github.com/fog/fog-azure-rm) as suggested by @engineersmnky in the comment but to resolve dependencies, bundler has to downgrade few gems e.g.:

```
Using faraday 0.17.6 (was 1.10.3)
Using faraday_middleware 0.14.0 (was 1.2.0)
Using elasticsearch-api 7.5.0 (was 7.17.7)
Using elasticsearch-transport 7.5.0 (was 7.17.7)
Using elasticsearch 7.5.0 (was 7.17.7)
```

That will break the app

Comment: I would try [`fog-azure-rm`](https://github.com/fog/fog-azure-rm/)

Comment: @engineersmnky that was my bet too. It turns, to resolve dependencies, bundler will downgrade few gems to make it work, e.g.: `Using faraday 0.17.6 (was 1.10.3);
Using faraday_middleware 0.14.0 (was 1.2.0);
Using elasticsearch-api 7.5.0 (was 7.17.7);
Using elasticsearch-transport 7.5.0 (was 7.17.7);
Using elasticsearch 7.5.0 (was 7.17.7)`
these changes will break the app.